# Validação de formulário Javascript funciona no IE mas não no Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Boa tarde a todos.
Estou tentando validar um formulário, verificando se o campo valor está preenchido e é maior que 0.

Funcionou perfeitamente no IE, mas no Firefox não funciona por nada no mundo!

Segue o código:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function valida(){
        f = document.form2;
        var valor = f.vlrass.value;

        if (valor==""){
           alert("Informar valor original da contribuição.")
           f.vlrass.focus()
           return false;
        }
           if (valor==0){
              alert("Informar valor original da contribuição.")
              f.vlrass.focus()
              return false;
           }
    }
    </script>
```

E a chamada do form:

```
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Listar Vencimentos"" onclick="return valida()">
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: 1º erro: `<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Listar Vencimentos" onclick="return valida()">` para `<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Listar Vencimentos"" onclick="return valida()">`

Answer (score 0):

Não creio que não vi a aspas que estava sobrando!!!! Era tudo culpa disto aqui:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Listar Vencimentos"" onclick="return valida()">
                                              Aspa sobrando! ^
```

Comment: acabas-te de publicar uma resposta, para comentar ou fazer alguma observação clica em "comentar" (mesmo por baixo da pergunta)

Comment: @CesarMiguel Ele publicou isto como resposta justamente porque achou o problema.

Comment: @Andrey, não tinha percebido que tinha encontrado a solução do problema. Pareceu-me mais um comentário antes de ser feita a edição.